# Is zerigo_dns:basic discontinued in heroku?

Tags: heroku

When trying to run:

`heroku addons:add zerigo_dns:basic`

I get

`Adding zerigo_dns:basic on mysite12345... failed
 !    AddonPlan not found.`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They discontinued the free plan a while ago. Click here to see the list of current plans.

https://addons.heroku.com/zerigo_dns